# Database structure design for different categories

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, directory-structure

I have two tables in my database...1st table named as `categories` contains all the parent categories and sub categories...as shown in the figure below...

```
    Categories_id   name            Parent_Categories
    1               art                 0
    2               entertainment       0
    3               music               2
    4               dance               3
    5               songs               3
```

now i have to create a 2nd table names as `Users_table` ..but the condition is ...
1)We can assign multiple categories id to each users...
2)multiple users can have same categories.
Below figure is the current database Structure.. Is ther any better way to do this??

```
 User_Id        Categories_id
    1           4,5
    2           1,2
    3           1,2,4
    4           1,5,4
```

Comment: Maybe create pivot/mapping table for this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users:

```
- UserID
```

UserCategory:

```
- UserID
- CategoryID
```

Category:

```
- CategoryID
- ParentID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table Users_table (User_Id integer,Categories_id integer, primary key(User_Id,Categories_id), foreign key (Categories_id) references categories(Categories_id);
```

...

`primary key(User_Id,Categories_id)` <--  multiple category ids can be assigned  to each user and only restricts duplicating of rows with same value.. So you can have multiple users having same category and a user having multiple category ids.. but not 2 rows with same user id and same category id

`foreign key (Categories_id) references categories(Categories_id)` <--  and this category id references the categories table

Answer (score 0):

Use Normalization in this case as like follows -

**1) users table** 
   - id 
   - username

**2) categories table**
   - id 
   - parent_category_id

**3) user_categories table**
   - id
   - user_id 
   - categories_id